# Multiple append calls in Jquery failing in IE 8

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax, append

So I'm working on a web application that uses jquery to parse xml data and add it to a table dynamically.  Theres four tables that get toggled on the same part of the page.  Here's the relevant html:

```
<div id = "toggleSection">
<div id = "autoPrevData"></div>
<div id = "firePrevData"></div>
<div id = "auto1Data"></div>
<div id = "auto2Data"></div>
<div id = "auto3Data"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the Jquery function with AJax:

```
    $("#autoEarly").click(function() {
        if (!$("#firePrevData").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#firePrevData").toggle('slow');
        }
        if (!$("#auto1Data").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#auto1Data").toggle('slow');
        }
        if (!$("#auto2Data").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#auto2Data").toggle('slow');
        }
        if (!$("#auto3Data").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#auto3Data").toggle('slow');
        }
        if (loadedModels[0]) {
            loadedModels[0] = false;
            $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "dashboard_auto.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXml_AutoEarly
        });
        }
        else {
            $("#autoPrevData").toggle('slow');
        }
        return false;

    });
```

And this is the function that actually parses the xml:

```
    function parseXmlEarlyPrevention(xml, xmlRoot, data) {
    //First Header
    $(data).append("<table><tr><th colspan='5'>Model Information</th><th colspan='4'>Score Metrics</th><th colspan='5' >Variable Metrics</th><th colspan='5' style='600;'>Pseudo-Standardized Coefficient Metrics</th></tr>");
    //Second headers
    $(data).append("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class='thickBorder'>&nbsp;</td><td colspan='2' style='font-size:1em; color:#888888; border-right:1px solid black'>PSI:</td><td colspan='2' style='font-size:1em; color:#888888; border-right:2px solid black;'>Divergence:</td><td colspan='2' style='font-size:1em; color:#888888; border-right:1px solid black;'>Divergence:</td><td colspan='3' style='font-size:1em; color:#888888; border-right:2px solid black;'>Largest Divergence:</td><td colspan='2' style='font-size:1em; color:#888888; border-right:1px solid black;'>Sum of Changes:</td><td colspan='3' style='font-size:1em; color:#888888;'>Largest Change in Relative Importance:</td></tr>");
    //Third Headers
    $(data).append("<tr><td>Model</td><td>Avg Rank</td><td>Benchmark</td><td>Current</td><td class='thickBorder'># in Curr Period</td><td>Rank</td><td class='thinBorder'>Value</td><td>Rank</td><td class='thickBorder'>Value</td><td>Rank</td><td class='thinBorder'>Average</td><td>1st</td><td>2nd</td><td class='thickBorder'>3rd</td><td>Rank</td><td style='border-right:1px solid black;'>Value</td><td>1st</td><td>2nd</td><td>3rd</td></tr>");

        var x = 1;
        $(xml).find(xmlRoot).each(function() {
            if (x % 2 == 1) {
                $(data).append("<tr>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue'><a href = 'modelInfo.php?model=" + $(this).find("model").text() + "$type=earlyPrev'>" + $(this).find("model").text() + "</a></td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue'>" + $(this).find("avg_rank").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue'>" + $(this).find("benchmark").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue'>" + $(this).find("current").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue thickBorder'>" + $(this).find("n_current").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue " + $(this).find("psi_color").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("psi_rank").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue thinBorder'>" + $(this).find("psi").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue'>" + $(this).find("divergence_rank").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue thickBorder'>" + $(this).find("divergence").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue" + $(this).find("var_color").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("var_div_rank").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue thinBorder'>" + $(this).find("avg_var_div").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue" + $(this).find("worst_div_col1").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("worst_div1").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue" + $(this).find("worst_div_col2").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("worst_div2").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue thickBorder" + $(this).find("worst_div_col3").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("worst_div3").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue" + $(this).find("psc_color").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("psc_rank").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue thinBorder'>" + $(this).find("sum_psc").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue" + $(this).find("worst_psc_col1").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("worst_psc_var1").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue" + $(this).find("worst_psc_col2").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("worst_psc_var2").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='dataCellBlue" + $(this).find("worst_psc_col3").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("worst_psc_var3").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("</tr>");
            }
            else {
                $(data).append("<tr>");
                $(data).append("<td><a href = 'modelInfo.php?model=" + $(this).find("model").text() + "$type=earlyPrev'>" + $(this).find("model").text() + "</a></td>");
                $(data).append("<td>" + $(this).find("avg_rank").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td>" + $(this).find("benchmark").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td>" + $(this).find("current").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='thickBorder'>" + $(this).find("n_current").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='" + $(this).find("psi_color").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("psi_rank").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='thinBorder'>" + $(this).find("psi").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td>" + $(this).find("divergence_rank").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='thickBorder'>" + $(this).find("divergence").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='" + $(this).find("var_color").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("var_div_rank").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='thinBorder'>" + $(this).find("avg_var_div").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='" + $(this).find("worst_div_col1").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("worst_div1").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='" + $(this).find("worst_div_col2").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("worst_div2").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='thickBorder" + $(this).find("worst_div_col3").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("worst_div3").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='" + $(this).find("psc_color").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("psc_rank").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='thinBorder'>" + $(this).find("sum_psc").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='" + $(this).find("worst_psc_col1").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("worst_psc_var1").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='" + $(this).find("worst_psc_col2").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("worst_psc_var2").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("<td class='" + $(this).find("worst_psc_col3").text() + "'>" + $(this).find("worst_psc_var3").text() + "</td>");
                $(data).append("</tr>");
            }
            x++;

        });
        $(data).append("</table>");
        $(data).toggle("slow");
    }
```

The problem is that only the html in the first $(data).append() call is being displayed and nothing afterwards.  It works fine in safari and firefox, but it's for work and I need it working on IE.  I've been pouring the internet for hours trying to find a good explanation but so far I've had no luck, and frankly its driving me a bit nuts.  Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM updates are expensive, and one would occur after each append in this situation. You're far better off building this up as ONE string and inserting it in one step.

Comment: How should I build this up as a string? I tried doing something to the extend of creating a var x and appending to that, only appending to data at the end, but that didn't work, although I could have been doing it wrong...

Comment: That would be the correct way. Perhaps there is another issue.

Comment: Well the issue that I've found is that only the first append is actually doing anything; for instance, when I load the webpage, only the table data from the first append loads up.

Comment: Nevermind, I actually just solved it. Turns out it was as simple as adding <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> to the top. Silly mistake, thanks for the help though.